# Static path to dynamic path issue in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I am trying to get the path for my page and I succeed to get it using an HTML image tag:

```
<img src="images/slider/<%# Eval("BannerImage") %>.jpg" alt="" />
```

Is there a way to make it dynamic using the asp:Image tag?

I tried to make it like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Classified/Images/Slider/'<%# Eval("BannerImage") %>'.jpg" />
```

And I got an error:

> The server tag is not well formed.

Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: The server tag is not well formed. I need to know how to combiend between a normal text and <%# Eval("BannerImage") %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
 ImageUrl='<%# "~/Classified/Images/Slider/" + Eval("BannerImage") + ".jpg" %>'/>
```